# Gatsby MDX Graph QL Queries not displaying my posts?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, blogs, gatsby-image

So it's been a while since I updated my Gatsby blog site, over 2 years and now when I updated all the packages, I noticed the markdown options have changed.

Orginally when I used this code, it would show all my blog post accurately with the correct images etc.

```
          export const query = graphql`
            {
              allMdx(
                filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/posts/" } }
                sort: { order: DESC, fields: frontmatter___date }
                limit: 6
              ) {
                nodes {
                  frontmatter {
                    alt
                    title
                    path
                    slug
                    date(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
                    image {
                      childImageSharp {
                        fluid {
                          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  id
                }
              }
            }
          `
```

However, now I tried to choose the options based on what I found from graphql that looks similar to my previous options

Here's the new updated code

```
          export const query = graphql`
            {
              allMdx(
                filter: { body: { regex: "/posts/" } }
                sort: { order: DESC, fields: frontmatter___date }
                limit: 6
              ) {
                nodes {
                  frontmatter {
                    alt
                    title
                    path
                    slug
                    date(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
                    image {
                      childImageSharp {
                        gatsbyImageData(layout: FULL_WIDTH)
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  id
                }
              }
            }
          `
```

However, this code only displays 2 post on my home page and doesn't show any of the images when I need all 6 to display and showcase all the images.

When I run the queries in graphql it only displays the 2 blog post data so I don't know which option to choose to reshow the same things I had before I updated my site with the new versions of gatsby

**Here's my gatsby-config file**

```
plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-react-svg",
      options: {
        rule: {
          include: /static/,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `GatsbyJS`,
        short_name: `GatsbyJS`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#f7f0eb`,
        theme_color: `#a2466c`,
        display: `standalone`,
        icon: `src/images/fav-1.png`,
        icon_options: {
          purpose: `any maskable`,
        },
      },
    },
    "gatsby-plugin-offline",
    `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
      options: {
        query: `
          {
            site {
              siteMetadata {
                siteUrl
              }
            }
  
            allSitePage {
              nodes {
                path
              }
            }
        }`,
        resolveSiteUrl: ({ site }) => {
          //Alternatively, you may also pass in an environment variable (or any location) at the beginning of your `gatsby-config.js`.
          return site.siteMetadata.siteUrl
        },
        serialize: ({ site, allSitePage }) =>
          allSitePage.nodes.map(node => {
            return {
              url: `${site.siteMetadata.siteUrl}${node.path}`,
              changefreq: `weekly`,
              priority: 0.7,
            }
          }),
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `posts`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/posts`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `resources`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/resources`,
      },
    },
    // {
    //   resolve: "gatsby-plugin-page-creator",
    //   options: {
    //     path: `${__dirname}/src/posts`,
    //   },
    // },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        extensions: [`.md`, `.mdx`],
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [{ resolve: "gatsby-remark-images" }],
      },
    },

    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`,
      options: {
        fonts: [`nunito\:400s,700`],
        display: "swap",
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-prismjs`,
            options: {
              classPrefix: "language-",
              inlineCodeMarker: null,
              aliases: {},
              showLineNumbers: false,
              noInlineHighlight: false,
              languageExtensions: [
                {
                  language: "superscript",
                  extend: "javascript",
                  definition: {
                    superscript_types: /(SuperType)/,
                  },
                  insertBefore: {
                    function: {
                      superscript_keywords: /(superif|superelse)/,
                    },
                  },
                },
              ],
              // Customize the prompt used in shell output
              // Values below are default
              prompt: {
                user: "root",
                host: "localhost",
                global: false,
              },
              // By default the HTML entities <>&'" are escaped.
              // Add additional HTML escapes by providing a mapping
              // of HTML entities and their escape value IE: { '}': '&#123;' }
              escapeEntities: {},
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
```

UPDATE: For index.js when I use this graph ql query I can finally see my images and the last 6 blog post I set, but not sure what I was supposed to input for the frontmatter so I just left it with empty {}

```
{
    allMdx(
      filter: { frontmatter: {} }
      sort: { order: DESC, fields: frontmatter___date }
      limit: 6
    ) {
      nodes {
        id
        frontmatter {
          title
          path
          slug
          alt
          date(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
          image {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid {
                src
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you share your `gatsby-config` and how you are looping through the posts to display them?

Comment: I added it and put a new query that gave me some results but still not sure about the posts because when I click on a blog post it will display the correct url in the browser, but show an error page

Comment: This implies an issue with the filesystem or the way Gatsby tries to generate the URLs for the posts. If the loop/image issue has been solved, can you update the question to remove the unnecessary code and share your `gatsby-node.js`?